# Xamarin Forms Entry invoke Completed event

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently working on a login and registration page within Xamarin Forms and after changing the done button of the keyboard to next and go on the last one I am no longer receiving the Completed event on Android (working fine on iOS). In the custom renderer I can catch the Control.EditorAction event which now acts the same as the Completed event but I can't seem to invoke the Completed event on the entry itself.

Within the EntryRenderer

```
Control.EditorAction += (object sender, TextView.EditorActionEventArgsargs) =>
{
    if (entryExt.ReturnKeyType != ReturnKeyTypes.Next)
        entryExt.Unfocus();

    // Call all the methods attached to base_entry event handler Completed
    entryExt.InvokeCompleted();
};
```

And within the EntryExt (which extends the Entry directly)

```
public void InvokeCompleted()
{
    Completed?.Invoke(this, null);
}
```

But the Completed event cannot be invoked due to the error

```
Error CS0070: The event `Xamarin.Forms.Entry.Completed' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= when used outside of the type `Xamarin.Forms.Entry'
```

Is there a way to invoke the Completed event? I'd rather not have a separate event handler for this within my views.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed the issue by changing

```
entryExt.InvokeCompleted();
```

inside the EditorAction to

```
((IEntryController)Element).SendCompleted();
```

which sends out the completed event back to the Entry base class.

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented a similar method of implementing this that allows the `Return` button to be extended to implement any type: Go, Next, Done, Send and Search.

## Sample App

[Here is a Xamarin.Forms app](https://github.com/brminnick/FaceOff) where I've implemented this approach. Feel free to download the repo and try it out!

#### 1. Create Custom Entry

In the Xamarin.Forms PCL, create a Custom Entry

```
public class EntryWithCustomKeyboardReturnButton : Entry
{
    public new event EventHandler Completed;

    public static readonly BindableProperty ReturnTypeProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<EntryWithCustomKeyboardReturnButton, ReturnType>(s => s.ReturnType, ReturnType.Done);

    public ReturnType ReturnType
    {
        get { return (ReturnType)GetValue(ReturnTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ReturnTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    public void InvokeCompleted()
    {
        Completed?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}

public enum ReturnType
{
    Go,
    Next,
    Done,
    Send,
    Search
}
```

#### 2. Create iOS Custom Renderer

In the iOS PCL, create this custom renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EntryWithCustomKeyboardReturnButton), typeof(EntryWithCustomKeyboardReturnButtonCustomRenderer))]
namespace Sample.iOS
{
    public class EntryWithCustomKeyboardReturnButtonCustomRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var customEntry = Element as EntryWithCustomKeyboardReturnButton;

            if (Control != null && customEntry != null)
            {
                SetKeyboardButtonType(customEntry.ReturnType);

                Control.ShouldReturn += (UITextField tf) =>
                {
                    customEntry?.InvokeCompleted();
                    return true;
                };
            }
        }

        void SetKeyboardButtonType(ReturnType returnType)
        {
            switch (returnType)
            {
                case ReturnType.Go:
                    Control.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Go;
                    break;
                case ReturnType.Next:
                    Control.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next;
                    break;
                case ReturnType.Send:
                    Control.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Send;
                    break;
                case ReturnType.Search:
                    Control.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Search;
                    break;
                case ReturnType.Done:
                    Control.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done;
                    break;
                default:
                    Control.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Default;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### 3. Create Android Custom Renderer

In the Android PCL, create this custom renderer

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(EntryWithCustomKeyboardReturnButton), typeof(EntryWithCustomKeyboardReturnButtonCustomRenderer))]
namespace Sample.Droid
{
    public class EntryWithCustomKeyboardReturnButtonCustomRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var customEntry = Element as EntryWithCustomKeyboardReturnButton;

            if (Control != null && customEntry != null)
            {
                SetKeyboardButtonType(customEntry.ReturnType);

                Control.EditorAction += (object sender, TextView.EditorActionEventArgs args) =>
                {
                    if (customEntry?.ReturnType != ReturnType.Next)
                        customEntry?.Unfocus();

                    customEntry?.InvokeCompleted();
                };
            }
        }

        void SetKeyboardButtonType(ReturnType returnType)
        {
            switch (returnType)
            {
                case ReturnType.Go:
                    Control.ImeOptions = ImeAction.Go;
                    Control.SetImeActionLabel("Go", ImeAction.Go);
                    break;
                case ReturnType.Next:
                    Control.ImeOptions = ImeAction.Next;
                    Control.SetImeActionLabel("Next", ImeAction.Next);
                    break;
                case ReturnType.Send:
                    Control.ImeOptions = ImeAction.Send;
                    Control.SetImeActionLabel("Send", ImeAction.Send);
                    break;
                case ReturnType.Search:
                    Control.ImeOptions = ImeAction.Search;
                    Control.SetImeActionLabel("Search", ImeAction.Search);
                    break;
                default:
                    Control.ImeOptions = ImeAction.Done;
                    Control.SetImeActionLabel("Done", ImeAction.Done);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### 4. Implement the Completed Event for Entry in Xamarin.Forms PCL

Here is a [link to some sample code](https://github.com/brminnick/FaceOff/blob/master/FaceOff/Pages/WelcomePage.xaml.cs) that shows how to implement the `Completed` Event in the Xamarin.Forms PCL.